# Different languages describing forefathers' wealth

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers, money

Off the top of my head, I bring three different verses describing the (enormous) wealth of our forefathers, each mentioning different parts of it:

- **Abraham**: "וְאַבְרָם כָּבֵד מְאֹד בַּמִּקְנֶה בַּכֶּסֶף וּבַזָּהָב׃" - "Abram was very rich in cattle, silver, and gold." [Genesis.13.2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.13.2?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)
- **Isaac**: "וַיִּגְדַּל הָאִישׁ וַיֵּלֶךְ הָלוֹךְ וְגָדֵל עַד כִּי־גָדַל מְאֹד׃ וַיְהִי־לוֹ מִקְנֵה־צֹאן וּמִקְנֵה בָקָר וַעֲבֻדָּה רַבָּה..." - "and the man grew richer and richer until he was very wealthy: he acquired flocks and herds, and a large household (slaves)..." [Genesis.26.13-14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.26.13-14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)
- **Yaakov**: "וַיִּפְרֹץ הָאִישׁ מְאֹד מְאֹד וַיְהִי־לוֹ צֹאן רַבּוֹת וּשְׁפָחוֹת וַעֲבָדִים וּגְמַלִּים וַחֲמֹרִים׃" - "So the man grew exceedingly prosperous, and came to own large flocks, maidservants and menservants, camels and asses." [Genesis.31](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.31?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0) (*there are some more on Yaakov, meeting Esov*)

While I don't see differences in lifestyles or cultures, the Torah uses different terms: e.g. money is mentioned with Abraham but not the others, camels and asses are mentioned with Yaakov, but not others, herds are mentioned with Isaac but clearly omitted with Yaakov.

Why?

Comment: Why should it use the same terms?

Comment: @Dov Because each term would probably hint at a different aspect of the wealth.

Comment: Surely al pi pshat there's not much more to look into?